# String which i get with voice rec does not working

Tags: android, string, voice-recognition

Here is my codes

@Override

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        String words = matches.get(0);
        doCommand(words);

    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

void doCommand (String command){
    word.setText(command);
    if (command == "hello")
        venus.setText("Hello Boss");
    else 
        venus.setText(":(");    
}
```

Textview word which is working with word.setText(command); shows that command string is "hello" but in if statement it doesnt work. It always goes to else. Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `String.equals(String other)` to compare 2 strings, i.e use `command.equals("hello");` here.

Comment: ok. Then check few things. Use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals` and check for any spaces or endline characters that might be in the string. It might be returning `hello `(with a space at end or start).

Comment: nope still doesnt work :( I can not understand word.setText(command); this code works and textview shows "hello" but when i check with if it goes to else i ll get crazy

Comment: On another point why are you calling super after your code? WHy not have `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` at the beginning and then write check your request code?